# MvvmCross Split view with Storyboard SplitViewController

Tags: mvvmcross

I am looking for an example of how to use the IOS Storyboard SplitView controller with MVVMCross.  I have looked at the samples in the MVVMCross playground, but these do not use the storyboard file.

Can anyone help with a pointer to a good example.  All information seems to be around 2013 and the examples are too old for the current version of the framework.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Playground sample in the main repository has some good samples on using Storyboards.

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/TestProjects/Playground/Playground.iOS/Views/ChildView.cs#L10

Documentation is also available on the website: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/platform/ios-user-interfaces-approaches#storyboards